# Como representar na UML métodos sobrescritos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, uml

Como representar na UML de classe quando um método deve ser sobrescrito?

Se basta apenas repetir o método da classe-pai para a classe-filha ou existe outra forma ou ainda, quem sabe, não se deve(se bem que acho isso pouco prático)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma forma universalmente correta, o que eu vejo que é mais comum fazer é colocar um método abstrato como itálico na classe original, deixando claro que ele deve ser sobrescrito por quem herdar a classe. Por coerência o nome da classe também deveria estar em itálico já que ela é obviamente abstrata também.

Como há uma implementação, você deve repetir o método na classe filha. Já vi algumas controvérsias quanto a isto, principalmente quando não herda de um método abstrato e apenas sobrepõe ao que já existe. Mas repetir me parece mais lógico. A omissão só deveria ocorrer quando o método da classe superior é usado sem nova implementação, o que obviamente é impossível se o método é abstrato.

Há quem goste de usar `<<abstract>>` acima do nome da classe. Pode ser uma boa para deixar visualmente mais explícito que a classe é abstrata. No método seria poluição visual mas alguns usam `<<virtual>>` na no método da classe superior e `<<override>>` no método que receberá a (nova) implementação.

Mas note que tudo isto que estou falando é em termos gerais. Alguns softwares de UML exigem certo padrão, especialmente se ele gerar código fonte à partir do diagrama de classes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado mais um vez @bigown, vc tem me ajuda muito.

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro!!

Comment: Na verdade, existe uma forma universalmente correcta. A [especificacao UML 2.5](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/) define o seguinte: "**The name of an abstract Classifier is shown in italics**, where permitted by the font in use. Alternatively or in addition, an abstract
Classifier may be shown using the textual annotation {abstract} after or below its name."

Comment: @dcastro obrigado pelo *link* estava procurando uma referência para postar para mostrar como é especificado.